# Not getting the right output with nested for loops in java

Tags: java, loops, nested

I was doing a simple exercise, my code should output a 5x5 board of #. It outputs vertical lines instead of horizontal.

```
public class SqareBoared_with_NestedLoops {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j <= 5; j++) {
                System.out.println("# ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

It outputs 5 vertical lines of #.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class SqareBoared_with_NestedLoops {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j <= 5; j++) {
                System.out.print("# ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Use System.out.print() method in inner loop.

print() method only prints the character(or String), but println() method print the character(or String) and the newline `\n` character at the end as well.

Comment: Oh, Thanks! I couldn't get my head around it.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `println()` in the inner loop, so you print a newline every time. Replace it with `print()`.

```
... 
for (int j = 0; j <= 5; j++) {
    System.out.print("# ");
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

To print `5` elements, your loop needs to go from `0` to `5` excluded.

Also, you need to print a line seperator only after having printed a full line of `5` elements:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        System.out.print("# ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A slight improved version with fix, Using a StringBuilder and print once per line

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    StringBuilder sb = null;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        sb = new StringBuilder(); 
        for (int j = 0; j <= 5; j++) {
            sb.append("# ");
        }
        System.out.println(sb.toString());
    }
}
```